# jQuery is not a function in anonymous function

Tags: jquery, anonymous-function

I am trying to write an anonymous javascript function that dynamically loads jquery and angular. However, when I run the function I keep getting 'jQuery is not a function'. Can someone help? Here is my code:

```
(function() {

  var jQuery;
  var jquery_tag = document.createElement('script');
  var angular_tag = document.createElement('script');

  jquery_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
  jquery_tag.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js");

  angular_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
  angular_tag.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js");

  jquery_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
  angular_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;

  (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(jquery_tag);
  (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(angular_tag);


  function scriptLoadHandler() {
    jQuery = window.jQuery
    main();
  }

  function main() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      alert('yo'); //this runs
    });
  }

})();
```

Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/p7jcofx1/4/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you update your jsfiddle to reflect your recent code changes?

Comment: Also, where exactly are you getting the error `'jQuery is not a function'`?

Comment: What would happen if angular loads before jQuery?

Comment: @apokryfos It would use inbuild jqLite

Comment: @A.Wolff yes but would `jQuery` exist?

Comment: @Matt i just updated my fiddle to show where the error is

Comment: @apokryfos `window.jQuery` would be undefined. I get your point! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scriptLoadHandler()` will run two times based on this code:

```
jquery_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
angular_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
```

Even though the Angular code is listed after the jQuery code, it could load first, making `window.jQuery` undefined in `scriptLoadHandler`, and causing `jQuery(document)` to fail in `main()`.

You can prevent this by updating `scriptLoadHandler` as follows:

```
function scriptLoadHandler() {
  if(window.jQuery) {
    jQuery = window.jQuery
    main();
  }
}
```

Comment: this solved it! also, if you don't mind, could you confirm that i'm loading the jquery and angular correctly / via best practices?

Comment: I honestly don't know what best practices are for loading scripts dynamically, but I don't see anything wrong with your code other than the risk that Angular could load first.

Answer (score 1):

From the angular documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

> To use `jQuery`, simply ensure it is loaded before the `angular.js` file. You can also use the `ngJq` directive to specify that jqlite should be used over jQuery, or to use a specific version of jQuery if multiple versions exist on the page.

You can achieve this using the following:

```
  var jquery_tag = document.createElement('script');          

  jquery_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
  jquery_tag.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js");          

  jquery_tag.onload = jQueryLoadedHandler;    

  (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(jquery_tag);      


  function jQueryLoadedHandler() {
    //Load angular after jQuery 
    var angular_tag = document.createElement('script');
    angular_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    angular_tag.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js");
    angular_tag.onload = angularLoadedHandler;
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(angular_tag);
  }

  function angularLoadedHandler() {         
      main(); //Both jQuery and angular should be loaded
  }

  function main() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      alert('yo'); //this runs
    });
  }
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7jcofx1/5/)

**Note:** This is a suggestion in the case you want `angular.js` to use jQuery. If you don't mind it using jqLite then this is not necessary and the accepted answer should work just fine.